# Visual Studio Code Terminal showing messages I don't understand that is not part of my code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gcc, g++, mingw

When I run my C++ code using Visual Studio Code with all necessary C++ plugins installed, it always shows these messages in the Terminal before actually displaying my code's intended output:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\(My username)\Coding projects>  & 'c:\Users\(My username)\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.18.5-win32-x64\debugAdapters\bin\WindowsDebugLauncher.exe' '--stdin=Microsoft-MIEngine-In-f52k25pf.nob' '--stdout=Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-dv4azz2x.qdg' '--stderr=Microsoft-MIEngine-Error-x3e3i25z.2ax' '--pid=Microsoft-MIEngine-Pid-intd1lwa.i0t' '--dbgExe=C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\gdb.exe' '--interpreter=mi'
```

I'm using MingW as a compiler and I chose g++ to run and compile this particular code.

Is this something unavoidable? I prefer to have a clear window to test my code if it's possible. I looked at all the other tabs (Problems, Output, Debug Console, Ports) but I don't find what I was looking for. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

I tried using gcc as a compiler instead, but nothing different happened.

Comment: Visual Studio is opening a shell to run your console-mode application. The shell it's using is Windows PowerShell, which pretty much always shows this text on startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry, what you're seeing in Visual Studio Code is completely normal! It's like a backstage pass to your program's performance. The tool is just giving you a peek into the nitty-gritty details, such as the arguments being used, the parameters in play, and even the interpreter that's doing all the behind-the-scenes work.